# react-nativeのreact-navigationで”戻った時”に画面を更新したい

Tags: react-native

react-nativeのreact-navigationで画面遷移を行っていますが
「←」で戻った際に、画面を更新するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

画面構成は「リスト」と「詳細」です。
「リスト」画面を表示している状態で”あるアプリ外からのトリガー”で「詳細」画面に遷移します。
そこから戻った時にリストを更新したいのです。

戻った時に「リスト」では何かイベントが発生するのでしょうか。
またStackNavigatorのonNavigationStateChangeでは画面遷移を捕捉できますが、
そこで「リスト」のインスタンスを取得できればいいのかもしれませんが
どうやって取得できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

`focus` イベントが使えます。

スタックされていた「リスト」スクリーンにフォーカスが戻ったとき、 `focus` イベントが発火します。

やり方としては３通りあります。

1. `focus` イベントをリッスンする
2. `useFocusEffect` hook を使う
3. `useIsFocused` hook を使う

公式ドキュメントに、詳細なコードサンプルが載っています。

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/